# asp.net cs variable in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need some help please. I've got an aspx page with an iframe and I'm trying to pass a variable called 'pageId' from my code behind to it. I've looked at various examples on SO and other sites and most suggest to others its a databinding issue and I've followed through some of the examples. Perhaps I can't use a variable like the way Im trying to do in an iframe?

I've introduced the get/set and public properties, but just a little lost. Anyone help point me in the right diection please?

aspx page

```
<iframe width="690" height="600" src="https://myserver.com/Index.php?pageId=<%=pageId%>" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="border-width: 0px;"></iframe>
```

aspx.cs page

```
protected String pageId { get; set; }

//private string pageId;
//public String pageId { get {return pageId; } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pageId = 'Y2840'; //this is generated from my db and I know the data is being stored in here as I have Response.Write(pageId)   
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Or what is not happening?

Comment: Im not hetting an error as such, but myserver.com/Index.php does not display the value of pageId. Its like there is nothing in there, but when I response write there is

Comment: is the iframe inside a FormView? otherwise might be easier to set an id on the iframe and set the src in code-behind.

Comment: The iframe is within the standard form tags? I'll look into FormView

Answer (score 2):

Your private variable and public property have the same name. Try using a capital P in your property name. Also don't declare a new variable pageId in Page_Load. PageId is blank because you are setting the local Page_Load method variable, and not the class level  variable.

```
private string pageId;
public string PageId { get {return pageId; } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageId = 'Y2840';  
}
```

In your aspx page:

```
<%=PageId%>
```

Comment: Weird, so did you remove string from the Page_Load method?

Comment: If I just add <%=PageId%> to my aspx page the variable is displaying out. However its not passing through to my server in the iframe. I think I'll try the formview method. Ooh So close.

Answer (score 0):

method 1.

```
<iframe runat="server" id="myiframe" width="690" height="600"      
frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"     style="border-width: 0px;"></iframe>
```

code-behind:

```
myiframe.src="https://myserver.com/Index.php?pageId=" + pageId;
```

method 2.

put iframe in formview and give it a datasource. Then use your existing code.